# Unusual behavior in Python syntax highlighting

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting

I have Emacs 28.1 installed via brew running on macOS Monterey. No further customization. When I open a very basic Python program, I get unusual syntax highlighting. See below for a screenshot; you can see that the assignment to `self.a` gets a different color from the assignment to `self.b`. This happens when I reopen the file, without even editing the buffer. What could be causing this?

[image: Broken syntax highlighting]

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Emacs does have a problem with Python highlighting, and I think it needs to be reported as a bug. https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bugs.html

Comment: Don't see this fontification bug in Emacs 29.0.50, seems fixed.